# how to extract images from a video file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to get one image out of an video to use as a thumbnail
So I am trying this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:34.05 -i input.avi -vframes 1 -sameq output.jpg
```

This works just fine however every once in a while I come across a file where this fails with the following error message

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error occurred
```

Usually that means that input file is truncated and/or corrupted.

*What are my options if any ?*
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i sample.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 320x240 -f image2 -y sample.jpg;
```

always set -ss before -i in order to optimize performance while grabbing thumbs from long length videos.

Answer (score 0):

I think is easier if you extract one of the first frames as a thumbnail.

Instead of -ss I use -vf thumbnail=num_frame

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf thumbnail=25 -vframes 1 -sameq output.jpg
```

Comment: I keep getting ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-vf'

Comment: -vf, videofilter is recognized if you active libavfilter  http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

ok this seemed to work for me 
ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible using ffmpeg.

-install ffmpeg in your server.
 -check below example code.

```
extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

// $vid = realpath('./video/Wildlife.wmv');

$video_url = 'http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4';

$image_filename = 'images/' . time() . ".jpg";

$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($video_url, false);

$frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();

$capPos = ceil($frameCount / 4);

$frameObject = $movie->getFrame($capPos);

if ($frameObject) {

    $frameObject->resize(500, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    imagejpeg($frameObject->toGDImage());

} else {

    echo 'error';

}
```