# Frame extraction disparity between ffmpeg and media player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flowplayer

My goal is to allow frame extraction from a video at a chosen time. Unfortunately I'm only getting the frame I see *most of the time*!

I am using ffmpeg to extract the frame with the following arguments:
    ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:01:13.000 -i INPUT.mp4 -vframes 1 OUT_%d.jpg
Some of the time I will get the frame that I see in the player at that time (players I have tested have been VLC and flowplayer), and some of the time the frame will be at a slightly different point (miliseconds out!).

I have also tried to accomplish the same by using mplayer but I was unsuccessful. Any ideas as to why would be appreciated.

Comment: Visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122719/how-to-extract-images-from-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/10123266#10123266) how to extract images from a video file using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `-ss` as an output option (after `-i INPUT.mp4`). The [changes the behavior](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-November/002976.html) of `-ss`:

- Used as an input option ffmpeg will attempt to seek to your time and
  then begin decoding; it is faster but potentially not accurate.
- When used as an output option ffmpeg will decode from the beginning of the
  file until your desired time. It is slower but often more accurate.

You may be able to increase decoding speed by applying `-threads` (with an appropriate value for your machine) as an input option.